# Angular: Components disappear when I add animations to components

Tags: angular, animation

So I was hoping to add animations to my web page. I at first tried difficult ones and that didn't work out (I'm very unfamiliar with angular animations). Now I tried a basic one, but even now it doesn't work.

I added a basic animation to the component. When the element enters the page I want the opacity to change from 0 to 1 over a time period of 2 seconds. When I have the animation property in my component decorator my template isn't showing in the browser (also no errors in the console). When I remove the animation it works like before and shows my component (without animation of course)

Can someone see where I'm wrong?

**Component decorator**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'find-locals',
    styleUrls: ['find-locals.component.css'],
    templateUrl: 'find-locals.component.html',
  animations: [
    trigger('tijl', [
      state('start', style({
        opacity: 0
      })),
      transition(':enter', [
        animate(2000)
      ])
    ])
  ]
})
```

**Template**

```
<div @tijl class="header-box header-box--left">
                <h3 class="profileSection__data">Content</h3>
              </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get it to work with the following:

```
  animations: [
    trigger('tijl', [
      state('start', style({
        opacity: 0
      })),
      transition(':enter', [
        style({ opacity: '0' }),
        animate(2000)
      ])
    ])
  ]
```

**[Here is a Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h54axq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
animations: [
    trigger('tijl', [
      transition(':enter', [
        style({ opacity: '0' }),
        animate(2000)
      ])
    ])
  ]
```

> animate will role back the style over 2 second

[**stackblitz demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fade-in)